# Access: How to Find the Total of entries in a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

How would you go from...

```
FirstName|LastName|Description|Sum of Payment Types
Stone    |Striclan|FICA       |-4001.56
Stone    |Striclan|Cost of Lab|20000.78
```

to

```
 FirstName|LastName|Total Pay
 Stone    |Striclan|15,999.22
```

Basically I'm just trying to add up all of the sum of payments for each name in a query, regardless of description. Could you go about this by using the firstname as a keyword or something? Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: having a sqlfiddle would be nice

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Would it be Total Pay:SUM(Sum of Payment Types)?

Comment: Access 2010 is what im using

Comment: you guessed it right, go that way and add `group by FirstName, LastName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic aggregation query:

```
select FirstName, LastName, sum([Sum of Payment Types]) as [Total Pay]
from YourTable
group by FirstName, LastName ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,sum(total_field_name) FROM table ORDER BY firstname,lastname;
```